# How to convert captureStillImageAsynchronously(sampleBuffer) to base64 encode in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How to convert captureStillImageAsynchronously(sampleBuffer) to base64 encode in Swift 3

I am trying to continuous feed image data to HTML web view, after finding ,no Cordova plugin can fit this goal, because I need the image/video data to draw on canvas so I can process it with js library.

Initially I wanted to use WEBRTC but it is only available for android. I am developing on IOS 9+.

Therefore I am trying to create a very simple plugin that show the preview for real time and feed the image data every .3 second(call with javascript Cordova pluging command), in order to process the image.

The swift tutorial for getting sampleBuffer:
http://drivecurrent.com/using-swift-and-avfoundation-to-create-a-custom-camera-view-for-an-ios-app/

The thing I need is convert captureStillImageAsynchronously sampleBuffer to base64 encode, or if there any other way to have the image data which can process by javascript?

```
   if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)

                let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
                self.capturedImage.image = image
                print(sampleBuffer) // how to convert this to 64encode ? without saving to camera roll
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Note that the function `captureStillImageAsynchronously(from:completionHandler:)` has been deprecated in iOS 10. The docs don't like a replacement method unfortunately. Searching with the phrase "captureStillImageAsynchronously deprecated" reveals that we should be using the `AVCapturePhotoOutput` class instead.

Comment: This question shouldn't really have the javascript tag.

Comment: I see, I removed the javascript tag now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `captureStillImageAsynchronously(from:completionHandler:)` is deprecated, as mentioned in my comment. You should update your code to use the new AVCapturePhotoOutput class instead.

As a general answer, you can convert NSData (Data, in Swift 3) to base64 encoded data using the method `base64EncodedData`:

```
let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
let base64Data = imageData.base64EncodedData([])
```

Comment: Thanks! really clear answer, the information is really helpful, let me try and I will get back to this question.